# How to add newline after occurrence of a specific word

Tags: ruby, string

How would I add a newline after every occurrence of a specific word `"Star"`? For example, let's say I have the string:

```
"Some Book Rated 3 Star Another Book Rated 2 Star"
```

I want to separate this line with newlines using `gsub`, but I cannot figure out how to do so.

Comment: What "specific" word are we talking about? What have you tried?

Comment: Oh god, so sorry, after every occurrence of "Star".

Comment: `s.gsub(/(?<=\bStar\b)/, "\n")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given this:

```
s = "Some Book Rated 3 Star Another Book Rated 2 Star"
```

To replace the word with the same word and newline:

```
s.gsub!("Star", "Star\n")
```

To protect the word boundary:

```
s.gsub!(/\bStar\b/, "Star\n")
```

To use capturing syntax:

```
s.gsub!(/\bStar\b/, '\0'+"\n")
```

To use non-capturing syntax:

```
s.gsub!(/(?<=\bStar\b)/, "\n")
```

Comment: whats the difference between capture and non-capture?

Comment: @Cyzanfar The capture and non-capture have the same result; the difference in a broader context is the non-capture is a bit safer, faster, and clearer about the goal, because there's no chance of the match accidentally slipping into the result. For example if you were searching/replacing passwords or confidential fields, you'd definitely want to use non-capture. I'd personally use non-capture syntax because it feels clearer to me that the only thing changing is a newline. (There may be other differences too if anyone else here wants to weigh in)

Answer (score -1):

Like this:

```
"Some Book Rated 3 Star Another Book Rated 2 Star"
.gsub(/(?<=Star)/, $/)
# => "Some Book Rated 3 Star\n Another Book Rated 2 Star\n"
```

Answer (score -1):

- \b Backspace
- \e Escape
- \f Formford
- \n Newline
- \r Return
- \s Space
- \t Tab
- \v Vertical tab

So if I did something like this:

```
puts "foo\n"
```

It would start a new line after foo

Or if I wanted to tab:

```
puts "\tfoo"
puts "bar"
```

It would like something like this:

```
    "Foo"
"Bar"
```

So on and so forth.